# Web App Authentication/Security Best Practice with Google Cloud Database (Bigtable)

Tags: authentication, firebase-authentication, google-authentication, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I am developing a webapp to access data in Bigtable in Vue and hosting it on Firebase Hosting and I am using Firebase Authentication to control user access for the app. I am curious as to best practices for authentication and security when it comes to such a use case.

I've read this:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/authentication

Here is my question:
I was taught once that the reason we build APIs in front of SQL servers for example was because we didn't want to expose the SQL server directly to the end user and risk bad things happening. So the API sits in between to act as a layer of protection.
In the Bigtable world, Google has provided their client SDKs for Bigtable that interacts with Google APIs but it has also suggested to use service account json files in most use cases. Wouldn't this be dangerous since the service account credentials then allows anybody who somehow finds it in the app files to do read or write to Bigtable and potentially mess up the database?
Should I build an API in front of Bigtable and use Firebase Auth to check if the client is authenticated using JWT before allowing operations? Or is there some other best practice?

Also,
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user
This article suggests that I use OAuth, so can it be linked to Firebase Authentication somehow?

Thank you!

Comment: Hey could you provide more info about why you chose Bigtable for this project? Its use cases are fairly specific and I wanna make sure you understand that before you get too far and end up with a huge bill for no reason.

Comment: Hey! Basically, I'm building an app for my company to store and visualise over 20k instrumentation sensors that will write data at regular intervals, so Bigtable seems to be a natural fit. The frontend app will be built in Vue just to plot out these sensor readings and provide a means for users to interact with the data. And it will be used by a large number of staff with different roles

Comment: Sounds like a great use case! I'm not too sure about how app authentication works, but you have the right idea. Create some kind of secure REST server that can communicate with your app and has authentication. You could also set up Cloud Functions for a serverless approach

Comment: Thanks Billy. Am I right to think that service accounts json in distributed javascript apps is a security risk and a bad idea?